# Dynamically change the meta tags of a React Js application using Express Backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-redux, meta-tags

I have been doing some research on dynamically changing the meta tags for my react Js application. I have tried so many solutions such as Helmet but I have not succeeded.
I will be glad if someone can give me a clear algorithm on this task. I have two backends one is in Express and another one in PHP. I created the Express backend purposely for this task yet I have not succeeded in getting the meta tags change when I share my link to other platforms like Facebook.

My current implementation.
Frontend:
My Index.html inside public has

```
    <title>$OG_TITLE</title>
    <meta name="description"        content="$OG_DESCRIPTION" />
    <meta property="og:title"       content="$OG_TITLE" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION" />
    <meta property="og:image"       content="$OG_IMAGE" />
```

Express Backend

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const port = process.env.PORT || 2800;

app.use('/api/dynamicmeta', (req, response)=>{
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './build', 'index.html')
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      data = data.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, 'Contact Page');
      data = data.replace(/\$OG_DESCRIPTION/g, "Contact page description");
      result = data.replace(/\$OG_IMAGE/g, 'https://i.imgur.com/V7irMl8.png');
      response.send(data);
    });
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './build')));
app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './build', 'index.html');
  response.sendFile(filePath);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!..`));

module.exports = {
  app
}
```

At this point, I am confused on how to continue because the title of my build doesn't change.